# Console logs undefined although the result is returned

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I solving an algorithm on one of the websites, but I cannot actually test my code because console shows undefined, although the result is returned. Please, can someone suggest me what is wrong with the code?

**The code**

```
function formatDuration (seconds) {
  // Complete this function
  var minutes = Math.round(seconds / 60);
  var thisSeconds = Math.round(seconds % 60);
  var hours = Math.round(seconds / 3600);
  var days = Math.round(seconds / 86400);
  var years = Math.round(seconds / 31536000);
  var stringYear = "year";
  var stringDay = "day";
  var stringHour = "hour";
  var stringMinute = "minute";
  var stringSecond = "second";

  if (years > 1) {
    stringYear = "years";  
  } else if (days > 1) {
    stringDay = "days";
  } else if (hours > 1) {
    stringHour = "hours";
  } else if (thisSeconds > 1) {
    stringSecond = "seconds";  
  } else if (minutes > 1) {
    stringMinute = "minutes"; 
  }

  if (minutes >= 60) {
    hours = Math.round(minutes/60);
    minutes = Math.abs(minutes - hours*60);
    if (minutes > 1) {
      stringMinute = "minutes"; 
    }
  } 

  if (hours >= 24) {
    hours = hours - 24;  
  }

  if (days > 365) {
    days = Math.abs(days - years*365);
  }

  var obj = new Map();
  obj.set(stringYear, years);
  obj.set(stringDay, days);
  obj.set(stringHour, hours);
  obj.set(stringMinute, minutes);
  obj.set(stringSecond, thisSeconds);

  var empArr = [];

  obj.forEach(function (value, key, mapObj) {

    if (value == 0) {
      obj.delete(key);   
    }

    var res = value + " " + key;

    if (value > 0) {
      empArr.push(res);
      formatStrings(empArr);
    }


  }); 

}

function formatStrings(arr) {
    return arr.length == 1 ? arr[0] : arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1).join(", ") + " and " + arr[arr.length - 1];
    //console.log(str);
}


formatDuration(3600);
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot find the log that is supposedly printing your result and the only return statement i can find is inside `formatStrings` which contradicts your statements.

Comment: `return` the formatted string in your `formatDuration` function. | Also, context, if anyone is interested: https://www.codewars.com/kata/human-readable-duration-format/train/javascript

Comment: You log `str` to the console log. It appears nowhere else. (And it's after the return; it won't actually log anything at all, so I don't know what you're talking about.) `formatDuration` returns nothing, so you'll get `undefined` back when you run it.

Comment: It logs to the console. What I want is to return the result. I cannot understand why the result is not returned.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have returned the **formatStrings** function like below.

```
function formatDuration (seconds) {
  // Complete this function
  var minutes = Math.round(seconds / 60);
  var thisSeconds = Math.round(seconds % 60);
  var hours = Math.round(seconds / 3600);
  var days = Math.round(seconds / 86400);
  var years = Math.round(seconds / 31536000);
  var stringYear = "year";
  var stringDay = "day";
  var stringHour = "hour";
  var stringMinute = "minute";
  var stringSecond = "second";

  if (years > 1) {
    stringYear = "years";  
  } else if (days > 1) {
    stringDay = "days";
  } else if (hours > 1) {
    stringHour = "hours";
  } else if (thisSeconds > 1) {
    stringSecond = "seconds";  
  } else if (minutes > 1) {
    stringMinute = "minutes"; 
  }

  if (minutes >= 60) {
    hours = Math.round(minutes/60);
    minutes = Math.abs(minutes - hours*60);
    if (minutes > 1) {
      stringMinute = "minutes"; 
    }
  } 

  if (hours >= 24) {
    hours = hours - 24;  
  }

  if (days > 365) {
    days = Math.abs(days - years*365);
  }

  var obj = new Map();
  obj.set(stringYear, years);
  obj.set(stringDay, days);
  obj.set(stringHour, hours);
  obj.set(stringMinute, minutes);
  obj.set(stringSecond, thisSeconds);

  var empArr = [];

  obj.forEach(function (value, key, mapObj) {

    if (value == 0) {
      obj.delete(key);   
    }

    var res = value + " " + key;

    if (value > 0) {
      empArr.push(res);
      formatStrings(empArr);
    }



  }); 

  return formatStrings(empArr);

}

function formatStrings(arr) {
    return arr.length == 1 ? arr[0] : arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1).join(", ") + " and " + arr[arr.length - 1];
    //console.log(str);
}


formatDuration(3600);
```